# Pygame is able to load images but gives a black screen

Tags: python, image-processing, pygame, event-handling, display

I made this code and when I run the program, I only get a black screen. There's no error about not being able to load images.

The code essentially goes like this:
1. Draw the map and the player (this part worked at some point but I don't have the last version of the code anymore)
2. Get the position of the player (this works)

These are the parts that don't work:
3. Update position of the player
4. Draw map & draw player again

```
import sys
import pygame
pygame.init()

print(pygame.ver)

#just to make it easier
false = False
true = True

#lenght and width of player image
xPlayer = 50
yPlayer = 50

#LOADED IMAGES
imagePlayer = pygame.image.load("image_player.png")
imageWall = pygame.image.load("image_wall.png")
imageStart = pygame.image.load("image_start.png")
imageFinish = pygame.image.load("image_finish.png")

#SCREEN
windowWidth = 500
windowLenght = 500
display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowLenght))

#maze and everything related
class maze:
    def __init__(self):

        self.gameOver = false
        self.width = 10
        self.lenght = 10
        self.map = [
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 3, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 0, 0,  0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 0, 1, 1,  0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [2, 0, 0, 1, 1,  0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        ]
    def drawMap(self):

        for i in range(0,self.width):
            for j in range(0,self.lenght):
                if self.map[i][j] == 1:
                    display_surf.blit(imageWall, (i*xPlayer, j*yPlayer))
                elif self.map[i][j] == 2:
                    display_surf.blit(imageStart, (i*xPlayer, j*yPlayer))
                elif self.map[i][j] == 3:
                    display_surf.blit(imageFinish, (i*xPlayer, j*yPlayer))

    def blitPlayer(self, positionHorizontal, positionVertical):
        display_surf.blit(imagePlayer, (positionHorizontal*xPlayer, positionVertical*yPlayer))

    def findPlayer(self):
        # TODO: find where player is and return value
        initialPositions = []
        initialPositionY = 0
        initialPositionX = 0
        initialPositionYBuffer = 0
        initialPositionXBuffer = 0
        foundPlayer = false
        while initialPositionXBuffer in range(0, self.width) and not foundPlayer:
            while initialPositionYBuffer in range(0, self.lenght) and not foundPlayer:

                if self.map[initialPositionXBuffer][initialPositionYBuffer] == 30:
                    foundPlayer = true
                    initialPositionY = initialPositionYBuffer
                    initialPositionX = initialPositionXBuffer
                initialPositionYBuffer += 1
            initialPositionXBuffer += 1
            if foundPlayer:
                initialPositions = [initialPositionX, initialPositionY]
            initialPositionYBuffer = 0
        return initialPositions

    def movePlayerTest(self):
        newPositions = self.findPlayer()

        while not self.gameOver:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
            self.drawMap()
            self.blitPlayer(self.findPlayer()[0], self.findPlayer()[1])
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.gameOver = True
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        newPositions = self.findPlayer()
                        newPositions[1] += 1
                        self.map[newPositions[0]][newPositions[1]] = playerNumber
                        self.blitPlayer(newPositions[0], newPositions[1])
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        newPositions = self.findPlayer()
                        newPositions[1] -= 1
                        self.map[newPositions[0]][newPositions[1]] = playerNumber
                        self.blitPlayer(newPositions[0], newPositions[1])
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        newPositions = self.findPlayer()
                        newPositions[0] -= 1
                        self.map[newPositions[0]][newPositions[1]] = playerNumber
                        self.blitPlayer(newPositions[0], newPositions[1])
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        newPositions = self.findPlayer()
                        newPositions[0] += 1
                        self.map[newPositions[0]][newPositions[1]] = playerNumber
                        self.blitPlayer(newPositions[0], newPositions[1])

pointCountP1 = 0
pointCountP2 = 0


playerNumber = 30
mazeDisplayed = maze()
print(mazeDisplayed.findPlayer())
#mazeDisplayed.drawMap()
mazeDisplayed.movePlayerTest()
```

What I get is a black screen. Even the drawMap method isn't working.

Comment: try printing a variable in each function called in this way you can find where exactly is the problem as @who says in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.drawMap()` and `self.blitPlayer` have to be done in the main loop rather than the event loop. [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) (or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)) is missing, it is needed to make the changes to the display visible.

```py
class maze:

    # [...]

    def movePlayerTest(self):
        newPositions = self.findPlayer()

        while not self.gameOver:

            self.drawMap()
            self.blitPlayer(self.findPlayer()[0], self.findPlayer()[1])
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                # [...]
```

Comment: exactly what i thought